# Server side and client side datasource filter in a kendo ui scheduler

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I'm working on a project where a Kendo UI scheduler is used. The scheduler is created with javascript. Because of performance the requirement is to load the data of a specific daterange (custom view) and then filter on the client. The problem is that when you use `serverFiltering = true` the client side filters do not work. Is there a way to load the visible dataset into the scheduler and then apply the client side filters?

The scheduler is loaded like this:

```
var scheduler = $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    date: new Date(),
    height: 600,
    views: [
        type: "month", eventHeight: 50},
            { type: "PlanboardView", selected: true, eventHeight: 60},
            { type: "timelineMonth", eventHeight: 50, majorTick: 1440, minorTickCount: 1 }
    ],
    dataSource: {
        batch: false,
        //serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            prefix: "",
            read: {
                url: "<the url>",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                if (operation === "read") {
                    var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");

                    var result = {
                        start: scheduler.view().startDate().toISOString(),
                        end: scheduler.view().endDate().toISOString()
                    }

                    return result;

                }
                if(operation != "read")
                {
                    return kendo.stringify(
                                options
                            );
                }

                return options;
            }
        }
    }

}).data("kendoScheduler");
```

for the next / previous navigation buttons I have:

```
function scheduler_navigate(e) {
    //e.preventDefault(); <-- when used, it's not reloading
    console.log("navigate function", e.date);

    this.dataSource.read();
    this.refresh();
    // when using this function and navigating to the next / previous range. The application Always takes the datarange from the visible dates before            
}
```

To bind this function to my scheduler I use: `scheduler.bind("navigate", scheduler_navigate);`

Comment: The only way to achieve this behavior that I can think of is to use two separate dataSources. One for loading the data from the server side, where the start/end date filters are applied and one which is bound to the scheduler and works with the data get from the first dataSource.